# MacBook Pro 15" not picking up external monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 15" laptop running Windows 7 Professional and for the life of me I just can't get it to connect to my 27" Dell U2711 monitor, using a Mini-DisplayPort to DVI adapter.

I am wondering if there is any known compatibility issues or whether I'm just approaching it wrong. I've installed the driver from Dell and still won't pick it up.

My graphics card is a GeForce 9600M GT. I've checked that:

- The monitor isn't working in OS X either
- The monitor is working with other PCs

Comment: @slhck No, it didn't. Yes forgot to mention. Mini-DisplayPort to DVI

Comment: @slhck Works with a PC yes

Comment: Finally, can you try if *any* other monitor works? That'd show us whether your graphics card is faulty — in that case, you'd have to have it repaired.

Comment: I am assuming your using the Apple adapter here: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A?

Comment: @Diago No, it does say Mini-DisplayPort to DVI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found that using a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable will sort the matter and is only around £7 a cable.

Answer (score 2):

If your using the Dual Link DVI adapter from Apple shown [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A) the monitor should work without any issues.

[image]

Although there are a few reported issues with it not working it is mainly due to the use of the incorrect adapter. This is the only adapter that will work.

All MBP's required the dual link DVI to drive non Apple 27" monitors and the older 30" Apple displays, however the new Thunderbolt Apple displays do not require the adapter as long as the monitor is directly connected to the port using a DisplayPort cable.

<sub>We run around 10 of these monitors at the office with MBP's, from 2010 upwards, and this was the only solution we ever found to work correctly</sub>

Comment: £70 is a bit hard to justify as its just a cable. Shame that's the only option really

Comment: @danRhul The issue is the amount of power needed to run the display and to be able to support the resolution, since often it is higher then the card itself can support. However, the new Thunderbolt displays and MBP's solve this problem.